# Solve y in terms of x: $ax + c\sin(y) - bx^3\cos(y) = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Im trying to determine what the geometric object given by:

\begin{equation}
\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: ax + c\sin(y) - bx^3\cos(y) = 0\}
\end{equation}

looks like, where $a,b,c$ are real constants. If I plug the expression into mathematica and solve for $y$, it gives a solution, but I cannot see the steps to get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd like to point out that it is not always the case that one should aim to get the same answer as Mathematica outputs.

To get you started, you may use the identity
$$
A\sin y+B\cos y=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\sin(y+\phi)
$$
(you get $\phi$ by using the addition formula for sine).

Can you take it from here? There will be a bit complicated due to the arbitrary constants in your equation.